# How do I create a taxonomy tag from node title

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a "Tags" vocabulary, and I would like to automatically add the node title to this vocabulary as a tag on saving the node. I have tried to use the Rules module to do this, but I can't get it to work.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend you doing that, you might get crazy node title names like "hello world I love peaches" and you dont want that tag.

anyway you can do a [Hook_node_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) in your custom module to add your code after creating a node, then you should use [taxanomy_term_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7) to insert your new term.

let me know if you need more on this.

Answer (score 0):

Give [Taxonomy_node](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_node) a chance, in the issue queue are patches to add the term to the node itself.

Nodes and terms are created, changed and deleted synchroniosly, it sounds like youu are searching for this. This module is for D6 in the moment.

There is a similar module: [Node Auto Term](http://drupal.org/project/nat) but I have not worked with it, it has a D7 - version.